# Xilinx Simulation Error Fuse:500

Tags: simulator, fpga, fuse, xilinx

I'm trying to simulate my VHDL code using Xilinx ISim.

When I try to generate the testbench for the simulation, the simulator throws up the following error:

```
FATAL_ERROR:Simulator:Fuse.cpp:500:1.133 - Failed to compile generated C file isim/
```

I tried to simulate it on an 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 using ISE 14.3, a 32-bit Windows XP SP3 also ISE 14.3 and a 64-bit Windows 7 SP1 same ISE version as before.

The Xilinx support provided a reinstall as solution, but that didn't solve the problem.

Maybe the community on Stack Overflow has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a tool crash and it's going to be hard to get an answer here on stackoverflow, at least without providing some code and the steps that cause the problem.  I would get back with Xilinx support and open a case -- this is something they need to fix in the tool.  Can you provide your code as a testcase to them?   Potentially cutting it down so it's as simple as possible while still causing the problem.

I can never provide production code to EDA vendors as a testcase due to confidentiality.  Quite often I find that while creating a smaller testcase that I *can* send that I'm able to also find a workaround to the original problem.  Try a binary search procedure -- remove or black box half of your design and see if the crash still happens.

And -- can you find the particular C file that fails to compile?  Looking at it may give a clue as to what in your design may be causing the problem.